# "Unbold" url in bibliography via .bst file

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

after creating an own .bst file via makebst I'd like to change the formatting of the url shown in the bibliography. Atm the URL is bold, I'd like to have it not bold, just standard.

The particular field in the bib-file is called *url*, type of document is *@misc*. The sections mentioning url in the bst file look like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{
  url
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\urlprefix\url{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

and

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ 
.
.
.
.
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL: }"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle{rm}\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
.
.
}
```

Inside the *@misc* function the url field is invoked by

```
  format.url output
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome, `bst` files are pretty cryptic. Using `biblatex` you can change the look of you bibliography easier.  From the snippets above, i really cannot say anything more productive.

Comment: From the code snippets you've provided, it looks like the URL strings are set in a monospaced (aka teletype, or tt) font face. In contrast, there's nothing in the code which would indicate that a **bold** font face is being used. Which monospaced font do you currently employ in your document? Some monospaced fonts can look quite heavy, giving the impression that a bold font face is being used. Do you simply want to use the standard (probably serifed) font face for URLs?

Comment: Hi,changing "texttt" to "textrm" doesn't change anything. And yes the standardfont would be great. The other fields are printed/shown just fine. I'm not at the computer, so I can't name the font atm. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Note that `makebst` and `urlbst` are different things – you mention the first, but have tagged it with the second. 2. Can you includes a minimal working example (MWE) which shows the problem? 3. I'd try changing `"\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}"` to include, say, `{xxx #1}`, to check that that _is_ where the `\texttt` is coming from. 4. That `\csname urlstyle{rm}\endcsname` looks... unexpected.